# What are limitation for making a Web Server with RPI 2?

Tags: web-server, operating-systems

I haven't used raspberry pi ever. I have ordered one and that's on way now. I was wondering if I use it as web server. Can I use centos on that? Are there any sort of limitations compared to tower/rack server?

Comment: This is a very broad question - have you done any research? There are many alternatives to running webservers on Linux, and the rPi runs Linux. There is no official release of Centos specifically for the rPi (see here: http://seven.centos.org/2015/03/centos-linux-7-and-arm/) but work is in progress. Other OS's, including the default raspbian, have nginx and apache as web server offerings, amongst others

Comment: No, I haven't done any research. I am totally new to linux. However, I am a php developer (working on windows). I just wanna learn how our web servers run (behind the scene).

Comment: Keep in mind that running servers on Linux is very different than running them on Windows. If you just want to learn how most of the Internet runs, the RPi can be invaluable as a learning resource. For all intents and purposes, the RPi will run just like any other Linux computer. For network-based services, there's not anything RPi-specific you need to worry about, other than the performance issues. The Raspbian RPi distribution has some unfortunate security defaults that you'll want to change, but that's about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little googling indicates that [some efforts](http://seven.centos.org/2015/03/centos-linux-7-and-arm/) are underway to port CentOS to ARM. Probably best to try a few basic searches for that sort of info.

You certainly can use a RPi as a web server, but you can't reasonably expect it to perform as well as a device costing 100 times more. Disk and network performance are restricted to USB speeds. For a small server, this may not be an issue. Memory is limited compared to a full rack server, so you may run into issues with complex sites or heavy usage. Again, may not be an issue. If you're doing other things on the RPi concurrently, you might run into issues.

It really comes down to what you want to do. The RPi can certainly be useful for learning about web servers, so long as you have reasonable expectations.

Comment: Let's put speed/performance aside. What are other issues? Are there any?

Comment: Not really.  It's a normal computer and you can run a normal GNU/Linux distro on it w/ pretty much any of the software you'd find in the x86 versions.  Just as bobstro says, it is not very powerful.  Like think of the cheapest smartphone you can find -- could you rig it up as a web server?  I guess, if you could find the right software.  In the case of the pi, yes you can find the right software and it's memory and CPU would support, e.g., a LAMP stack.  Depends what you add to that.  If you know what mem you normally need, you already know the answer to that.  If you don't, you'll be ok ;)

Comment: To add to goldilocks' comments: If you want to learn about _lightweight_ web servers, the RPi will work well. If you want to learn about state-of-the-art heavy configurations running a multitude of services, you might have some limitations. I think for training, it will do what you want, if only slowly. You can certainly do PHP on it, if you must.

Comment: thanks guys, I guess it's only speed issue. But that won't affect on learning things.